# How to select the hidden radio button using ruby capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

```
<tr>
<td>
    <div align="right">
        <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="red"/>
        <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#004891">Material type :</font>
    </div>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="radio" onclick="radioInsert='01'" name="rdInsertType"/>
    <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#004891">
        Promotion                                                                                                                
        <input type="radio" onclick="radioInsert='02'" name="rdInsertType"/>
        Important Notice  
    </font>
</td>
```

I have tried the following code :

```
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false

session.find(:xpath, ".//*[@name = rdInsertType]", :match => :first).click
```

and

```
session.execute_script("('input').show()")

session.choose('Promotion', visible: false)
```

but no use. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: what exception do you get?

Comment: Selenium is designed to NOT interact with hidden elements since users can't do the same. Why is the element hidden? How would a user get access to this element? Follow what a user would do to unhide the element and interact with it.

Comment: Did you try using -
page.execute_script('$(<element>).click()')